# symfony doctrine schema create

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am in the test files, and I want to launch some symfony commands namely a database followed by a drop followed by a create i create schema:

```
public function runCommand(Client $client, $command)
{
    $application = new Application($client->getKernel());
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $fp = tmpfile();
    $input = new StringInput($command);
    $output = new StreamOutput($fp);

    $application->run($input, $output);

    fseek($fp, 0);
    $output = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $output = fread($fp, 4096);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    return $output;
}
```

public function cleanDataBaseTest()
    {

```
    $client = self::createClient();        

    $command_drop_database = $this->runCommand($client, 'doctrine:database:drop --env=test --force');

    $command_create_database = $this->runCommand($client, 'doctrine:database:create --env=test');

    $command_create_schema = $this->runCommand($client, 'doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql');

    echo $command_create_schema;
  /*
    ALTER TABLE.....

*/

}
```

or when I do a echo $ command_create_schema, I only alter table.

```
    C6 FOREIGN KEY (akey) REFERENCES atable (id);
ALTER TABLE atablea ADD CONSTRAINT FK_646DFFB72576E0FD FOREIGN KEY (anid) REFERENCES ....
```

So if I'm doing command: php app / console doctrine: schema: create - dump-sql I get the create and alter table

Do you know why ?